# Digikam Facebook upload fails upon Change_Account: "User must specify a valid extended permission or data permission"

Tags: facebook, digikam

I'm trying to authorise the KDE KIPI Import/Export Plugin to uplead photos to Facebook.  I'm using Digikam 3.5.0.  After I select the URI from my browser window (the one containing `access_token=...`) and proceed, Digikam fails to authorise itself and instead gives the error message:

> *Facebook Call Failed: User must specify a valid extended permission or data permission (100)*

I used this plugin recently, did something change?

Comment: Same for me, looks like Facebook changed something on their end.

Comment: I'm using Digikam 4.9.0 on KDE 4.14.2. Previously one could copy in the URI, broken in the last month or two.

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347194 is the relevant bug, which is apparently fixed in 4.12.0.